# Do I have to write the same constructor for derived classes in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm making a chess game, and I'm laying out the classes. It makes sense to have a base Piece class, and separate Rook, Bishop, Knight, Pawn, King, and Queen classes to inherit from it. The only parameter the constructor will need is a boolean "owner" value (which will be a member of the base class): true for player, false for AI. I think the objects should be instantiated like this:

```
//create a Rook owned by the player
Rook exampleRook = new Rook(true);
//create a Knight owned by the AI
Knight exampleKnight = new Knight(false);
```

It seems like I would have to do something like this in *each* derived class:

```
Rook(bool owner) {
    this->owner = owner;
}
```

Which seems to violate the whole principle of inheritance: write code once in the base class, and then inherit. I might have to write a setOwner() function in the base class, but it seems to make more sense to set the owner in the constructor instead of in a separate function (which could be called again).

Comment: Your code looks like Java. Are you sure it is C++? If it is, search for "inheriting constructors".

Comment: 1. Inheriting constructors, 2. Member initializer lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the member initialization in the base class constructor's initialization list

```
Piece(bool _owner) : owner(_owner) {}
```

Then in the derived classes just pass through to the base class constructor

```
Rook(bool owner) : Piece(owner) {}
```